# geocoder.geocodeAddressString no longer works with swift update today

Tags: xcode, swift, clgeocoder

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/releasenotes/General/APIDiffsMacOSX10_11/Swift/CoreLocation.html

shows that there were a couple of changes

```
func geocodeAddressString(_ addressString: String!, completionHandler completionHandler: CLGeocodeCompletionHandler!)
```

to:

```
func geocodeAddressString(_ addressString: String, completionHandler completionHandler: CLGeocodeCompletionHandler)
```

my code was:

```
var geocoder = CLGeocoder()

geocoder.geocodeAddressString("\(event!.street), \(event!.city), \(event!.country)", completionHandler: {(placemarks: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if let placemark = placemarks?[0] as? CLPlacemark {
        self.event!.lat = placemark.location!.coordinate.latitude
        self.event!.long = placemark.location!.coordinate.longitude

        self.event!.getMiles(self.currentLocation!.location!.coordinate.latitude, clong: self.currentLocation!.location!.coordinate.longitude)
        var mile = self.event!.miles != nil ? NSString(format: "%.1f miles", self.event!.miles!) : "Location services off"
        self.milesButton.setTitle(mile as String, forState: .Normal)
    }
})
```

tried:

```
var geocoder = CLGeocoder()
let address = "\(event!.street), \(event!.city), \(event!.country)"
geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: {(placemarks: [CLPlacemark]) in
     let placemark = placemarks[0]
     self.event!.lat = placemark.location!.coordinate.latitude
     self.event!.long = placemark.location!.coordinate.longitude
     self.event!.getMiles(self.currentLocation!.location!.coordinate.latitude, clong: self.currentLocation!.location!.coordinate.longitude)
     var mile = self.event!.miles != nil ? NSString(format: "%.1f miles", self.event!.miles!) : "Location services off"
     self.milesButton.setTitle(mile as String, forState: .Normal)
})
```

it just keeps saying that its not allowed.  tried a few different combinations. this is do to the latest update to xcode / swift

thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `geocodeAddressString` this way:

```
geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: {(placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

})
```

And it will work fine.

Comment: Happy to help you..:)

Answer (score 10):

In Swift 2:

```
geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: {(placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

})
```

In Swift 3, replace `NSError?` with `Error?`:

```
geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: {(placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: Error?) -> Void in

})
```

Or, easier, just let it infer the correct types for you:

```
geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address) { placemarks, error in

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: {(placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

})
```

Just change `NSError` to `Error` and will it work

Answer (score 2):

This no longer works....

```
  geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: {(placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        print("Test")
    } as! CLGeocodeCompletionHandler)
```

throws an EXC error