# GLGeocoder geocodeAddressString crashes SWIFT 3

Tags: swift3, core-location

Why do I get a `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` with just an empty call to `geocodeAddressString`:

```
geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: {(placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in 

} as! CLGeocodeCompletionHandler)
```

Comment: try to remove 'as! CLGeocodeCompletionHandler', why are you force casting?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32655247/geocoder-geocodeaddressstring-no-longer-works-with-swift-update-today

Comment: Because the Swift compiler keeps putting the cast in the code.

Comment: that question in stackoverflow did not solve my problem

Comment: then for your issue you need to provide more input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in your case is that `error` is an `Error?` reference in Swift 3, no longer a `NSError?`. Thus your forced cast is failing. You can fix that like so:

```
geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: {(placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: Error?) -> Void in

} as! CLGeocodeCompletionHandler)
```

But that `as! CLGeocodeCompletionHandler` is not needed. If it suggested that cast, it probably only did so because it noticed that your closure was not of the right type.

Frankly, even easier, just let it infer the right types and you don't have to worry about this sort of issue:

```
geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address) { placemarks, error in 

}
```

Comment: I thought I had tried it with error also, but, anyway your second variant does work ... thanks.

Comment: Make sure you're using [weak self]  in that callback or you could crash.

Comment: @Gargoyle - No, it won't crash if we don't do `[weak self]`. Using `[unowned self]` could easily crash, but not just omitting `[weak self]`. As to whether you use `[weak self]` or not is merely a question of whether you need to keep a strong reference to the object in question or not. If it's merely updating UI controls, then `[weak self]` is a good idea. But if you're doing other stuff, too (e.g. updating model or persistent storage), then keeping the strong reference might be more appropriate. It just depends upon what you're doing in that closure.

Comment: If you don't use weak you'll run into issues where the geocode starts and then the person navigates away from the view controller.   If you capture a strong reference to self then you have a retain cycle as the VC has you and you have it.

Comment: That is simply not true. It is simply a strong reference, but one that is resolved as soon as the geocode call finishes or times out. But it's not a cycle. Yes, there are times that you absolutely must use weak references in closures to avoid strong reference cycles (when the object has a strong reference to that closure, itself), but this is not one of those cases.